# Which country do Mailinator's disposable SMS belong to and can this be altered?

Tags: sms, mailinator

[Mailinator's disposable SMS](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=16780325) (see [news announcement archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20180618090519/https://mailinator.blogspot.com/2018/04/mailinator-launches-disposable-sms.html)) seems to be a bit of a hidden feature. First you have to search for an e-mail address and only then click the Public SMS option. But it always seems to default to a fixed number.

Which country does this number belong to?

And what if you change it in the right side and click "GO!"? Does it switch to an e-mail address or to a different number?

[image: Public SMS]
[image: Change number]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems to be an US number: https://www.whitepages.com/phone/1-201-381-4330.

More specifically, [1 is the US' international country calling code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_country_calling_codes#Zone_1:_North_American_Numbering_Plan) and [201 is New Jersey's area code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Area_codes_201_and_551).

It also seems to be the only number available there, so this service is only good if the sender can send to a US number.